# Is there a Web Service Method like SPWeb.GetListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Using an OOB SharePoint 2010 web service, I need to update a document's metadata using its URL.

URL structure looks like this:
    [http://web/managedPath/siteCollection/library/folder1/folder2/..../doc.docx]

The updating will be done from a 3rd party app and doesn't contain any SharePoint DLL's.

Using a SharePoint .Net app, I can use the [spweb.getlistitem(path)] to work with the document. 
But, how do you do the same via a web service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lists web service in:

http:///_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

Documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

How to get a collection of ListItems based on a CAML query (this uses the proxy objects generated by Visual Studio, you you are using other technology then you need to build the soap request object etc):

```
Web_Reference_Folder.Lists listService = new Web_Reference_Folder.Lists();
listService.Credentials= System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"Query","");
XmlNode ndViewFields = 
    xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"ViewFields","");
XmlNode ndQueryOptions = 
    xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"QueryOptions","");

ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = 
    "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" + 
    "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='Field1' />
    <FieldRef Name='Field2'/>";
ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name='Field1'/>" + 
    "<Value Type='Number'>5000</Value></Gt><Gt><FieldRef Name='Field2'/>" + 
    "<Value Type=
        'DateTime'>2003-07-03T00:00:00</Value></Gt></And></Where>";
try
{
    XmlNode ndListItems = 
        listService.GetListItems("List_Name", null, ndQuery, 
        ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
    MessageBox.Show(ndListItems.OuterXml);
}

catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message:\n" + ex.Message + "\nDetail:\n" + 
        ex.Detail.InnerText + 
         "\nStackTrace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: thanks luis. My hope was to find a way to update an item at the Web level.  I'm able to accomplish this in a SharePoint app or PowerShell.  If there isn't a way, I'll try and work with the Lists.asmx service.

Comment: What do you mean by "My hope was to find a way to update an item at the Web level"?